# How can I get a repr of a DataFrame that is a valid Python expression?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, repr

I would like to unit test some code that returns a `pd.DataFrame`. The code already returns the correct value, and I'd like to use `pd.testing.assert_frame_equal` to assert that it returns this value so that if I change the code later I can catch regressions.

Many types in Python have a `.__repr__()` method that returns a valid Python expression that can be used to reconstruct the object. When I want to write this sort of test for one of these types, I can run

```py
actual = my_func()
print(repr(actual))
```

and then the test is

```py
def my_test():
    actual = my_func()
    expected = <what was printed>
    assert actual == expected
```

However, `DataFrame`'s `__repr__()` method does not return a Python expression. Is there a way that I print out some Python code that reconstructs the dataframe?

Using [`DataFrame.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and then passing that to `DataFrame.__init__` is close:

```py
def my_test():
    actual = my_func
    expected = DataFrame(<output of print(actual.to_dict())>)
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(actual, expected)
```

But this falls apart when `actual` is empty, because the column types can't be inferred, and this is the case I'm trying to test.

Comment: you could pickle the dataframe to a BytesIO object, though that's a weird "repr"

Comment: why are you round-tripping through a string? why can't you just test actual vs. expected? can you provide more context on the question so we can help with the root issue?

Comment: Why can't you use [DataFrame.equals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) to compare dataframes? I would also suggest using a testing module like [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html).

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I would like to test actual vs expected, but the dataframe is complicated and it's a lot of work to type out the Python code for the expected value. I want a way for Pandas to generate this code for me.

Comment: @Kraigolas yeah, I could use DataFrame.equals, although `pd.testing.assert_frame_equal` seems like it's intended for exactly what I'm doing. I'm actually already using pytest.

Comment: Are you saving the string and testing against the string? Why not just save as a pickle or some other file and read it back in? If the dataframe is complex you're not going to save yourself any headache trying to invent a round-trip-able repr. Just store the result.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I think it's more readable and easier to review/audit if it's Python code, even if it's a long gnarly chunk of Python code. A pickle file would work but you'd have to trust on faith that it's right and you'd have to regenerate the whole thing if something minor changes (e.g. adding a new column).

Comment: I actually solved this problem already by just manually typing the code, but I'm still interested in the answer. I suspect the answer is "this feature doesn't exist" and so I [filed a feature request against Pandas to implement it](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41837). Will leave this question open anyway in case the functionality already exists and someone can provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [Is there a way to print a pandas data frame as copyable code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912882/is-there-a-way-to-print-a-pandas-data-frame-as-copyable-code)

They use `to_dict()` like you attempted, but then use `DataFrame.from_dict()` to load the copy-pasted code.

Comment: This doesn't work when the dataframe has no rows, because the dict representation loses the type information in that case.